# Can't remove spaces between <td>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a "register" page in HTML and I made the table to the center. But when I moved the table to the center there was a huge gap between 's.
I tried "cellspacing" but it doesn't work since im working with HTML5.
I also tried "border-spacing:0px;" but it doesn't work either.

I'm using latest version of Chrome and Sublime Text

Code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #8F3985;
}

table.tablo {
  background-color: #07BEB8;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 650px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="tablo">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Adı:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Soyadı:
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Cinsiyeti:
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Erkek
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Kadın
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Yeri:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Bulgaristan</option>
          <option>İstanbul</option>
          <option>Ankara</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Tarihi:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>Ocak</option>
          <option>Şubat</option>
          <option>Mart</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>2000</option>
          <option>2001</option>
          <option>2002</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Kaydet">
        <input type="reset" name="" value="Temizle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: There's a huge gap because you're setting the table to be 600px wide. Regardless, in 2009 you shouldn't have been using tables to create layout, much less in 2019.

Comment: May I ask you where did you learn to write HTML?

Comment: I agree with @RobbyCornelissen...try to use something like bootstrap, the easiest way to create a cool responsive layout... https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: In school, they teach 2011's documentation.

Comment: I would love to use Bootstrap and other layout languages but I'm forced to write in old HTML.

Comment: Merhaba! do you must use table?

Comment: Yes, I'm forced to use tables. I can't use anyting else because our Web Development lessons has started recently.

Comment: Tamam :) so instead set `width/height` to `table` set `width/height` to `td/tr`  because the space is because the sizing that you give to the table

Comment: @aliozgurr Do a css reset. Add `* { padding:0; margin:0; }` to your css.

Comment: If you must use tables for layout, add the attribute `role="presentation"` to your table element. That will stop screen readers from trying to treat it as a real table and confusing their users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime when any style issue is there the reason can be style of parent control. In this case Table is nested inside Form control, so need to change style of form control first,after changing style of form position has change and for space little change in padding of table.

```css
body {
  background-color: #8F3985;
}

table.tablo {
  
  background-color: #07BEB8;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;  
  width: 650px;  
  padding: 50px;  
}


form {    
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="tablo">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Adı:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Soyadı:
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Cinsiyeti:
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Erkek
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Kadın
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Yeri:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Bulgaristan</option>
          <option>İstanbul</option>
          <option>Ankara</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Tarihi:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>Ocak</option>
          <option>Şubat</option>
          <option>Mart</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>2000</option>
          <option>2001</option>
          <option>2002</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Kaydet">
        <input type="reset" name="" value="Temizle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this result?

**Edit**

removed `height: 650px;` from `table.table`

The height for each row was too high because You set the height of the table to a specific value [in your case 650px] and row heights were evenly distributed. 
The solution is either to remove the height property or adjust the height according to your need.

Please note, this will not guarantee browser compatibility. It will be good to go with proven CSS frameworks like bootstrap to achieve the same result with responsiveness and browser compatibility.

```css
body {
  background-color: #8F3985;
}

table.tablo {
  background-color: #07BEB8;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 600px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table class="tablo">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h3>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="20%">
        Adı:
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Soyadı:
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Cinsiyeti:
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Erkek
        <input type="radio" name="durum">Kadın
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Yeri:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>Bulgaristan</option>
          <option>İstanbul</option>
          <option>Ankara</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Doğum Tarihi:
      </td>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>Ocak</option>
          <option>Şubat</option>
          <option>Mart</option>
        </select>
        <select>
          <option>2000</option>
          <option>2001</option>
          <option>2002</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Kaydet">
        <input type="reset" name="" value="Temizle">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for to remove spacings between textboxes.

Comment: while answering with code, you must include a minimal explanation. Then only op can understand what's wrong with their code.

Comment: @aliozgurr Which spacing? The answer above has no spacing. I am confused.

Comment: The spacing between <tr>

Comment: @aliozgurr the text boxes are in tr and the title of your question says td. Clarify it

Comment: @aliozgurr Do a css reset . Try adding `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }` , does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

These properties should work.

```
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody, tr {
    width: 100%;
}
table.tablo, table.tablo * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.tablo {
    width: 600px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #07beb8;
}
table.tablo td {
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0; /* change in whitespace you like */
}
table.tablo td:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and use for the header

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h3 style="text-align:center;">Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h3>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css code, you have fixed the **height = 600px**, which actually takes control of the inner size of the table and stretches table to become **600px** in size. To use **border-spacing**, you can just remove the *height* of table and update the value of *border-spacing*, then it will show you the actual spacing that you want to use in it.

I have updated your code below, just run and enjoy ;)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  background-color:#8F3985;
 }
 table.tablo{
   background-color:#07BEB8;
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width:600px;
     border-spacing: 5px;
 }
</style>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <table class="tablo">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <h3 style="text-align:center;">Kullanıcı Bilgileri</h3>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Adı:
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Soyadı:
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Cinsiyeti:
    </td>

    <td>
     <input type="radio" name="durum">Erkek
     <input type="radio" name="durum">Kadın
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Doğum Yeri:
    </td>
    <td>
     <select>
      <option>Bulgaristan</option>
      <option>İstanbul</option>
      <option>Ankara</option>
     </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Doğum Tarihi:
    </td>
    <td>
     <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
     </select>
     <select>
      <option>Ocak</option>
      <option>Şubat</option>
      <option>Mart</option>
     </select>
     <select>
      <option>2000</option>
      <option>2001</option>
      <option>2002</option>
     </select>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="submit" name="" value="Kaydet">
     <input type="reset" name="" value="Temizle">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to blue table go to all the way down and center the inputs without adding extra tables. This doesn't work for my demands.